# Getting Invalid root in registry key when running CScript.exe from a windows Cmd file

Tags: c#, cmd, jscript, wsh

I am running a test.cmd file from a C# exe by creating a System.Diagnostics.Process.

The test.cmd is launching a JScript file using the Windows Scripting Host Command Line as below

```
C:\myfolder>CScript.exe //Nologo testxml.js

testxml.js is running on localhost
==== Begin regenerating Xml  ====
Invalid root in registry key "HKCR\CLSID\{5D1D2C1E-F343-10D2-93B4-00902710D4AD}\
LocalServer32\\".
Failed to regenerate Xml for transaction
```

But the key actually exists in the registry. I am able to look into it and modify it manually.

I tried changing permissions to the registry key but no use.

Please help me on how to resolve this error.

I am using a Windows 10 x64 machine.

below is the code of my test.cmd

```
@echo off
Cscript.exe //B
goto start
:start
@echo on
CScript.exe //Nologo testxml.js
:end
@echo off
```

Comment: Is that registry key created in the js? If it is, please show how.

Comment: No. The registry key was the key of an installed product from install shield.

Comment: One more thing forgot to mention, when I am running the cmd file manually from command prompt, it is working fine. Only when I am launching the cmd file from the C# process I am getting the error.

Comment: The `CLSID` key is derived from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and differs between 64 and 32 bit. Are you sure C# is running the correct bitness process?

Comment: I built the exe in release mode by selecting "Any Cpu" as the target platform. Hope this should be fine with both 32 bit and 64 bit

Comment: I’d try checking under `HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID` to see if the key exists in the 32 bit subsystem. [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524094/692942).

Comment: tried Wow6432Node but the same error. Invalid root in registry key "HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{5D1D2C1E-F343-10D2-93B4-00902710D4AD}\LocalServer32\".

Comment: It definitely sounds like a classic bitness issue. Just because an executable is compiled using "Any CPU" doesn’t mean it can automatically distinguish subsystems just that it can run on them. If a program like InstallShield runs in 32 bit, it will probably store it’s registry keys in the 32 bit subsystem and vice versa. You just need to workout where they are stored and match the bitness.

Comment: oMaybe this is related to [Nested Wow6432Node key in InstallShield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8183869/692942)? Is it possible an extra `Wow6432Node` is being created? Is the InstallShield package part of the code?

Comment: I just skipped the RegRead function of the WScript.Shell and tried to create some component - using WScript.CreateObject(" MyServiceWrap.TestDirectoryWrap") -that was already registered in the system. It is also failing Could not create object named "MyServiceWrap.TestDirectoryWrap".  could this be the problem with accessing WScript.Shell functions?

Comment: You would only be able to access `MyServiceWrap.TestDirectoryWrap` if it is exposed to COM and registered using the correct bitness. Otherwise you’ll the classic "Class not registered" error.